# How to print part of a list on a new line in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

This may be a silly question, but I'm very new to Haskell. (I just started using it a couple of hours ago actually.)

So my problem is that I have a list of 4 elements and I need to print two on one line and two on a new line.

Here's the list:

```
let list1 = ["#", "@", "#", "#"]
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
#@
##
```

I know that i could use the following to print every element on a new line:

```
mapM_ putStrLn list1
```

but I'm not sure how to adapt this for only printing **part** of the list on a new line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like `Data.Text.chunksOf` for arbitrary lists, which I've never seen anywhere so I always reimplement it.

```
import Data.List (unfoldr)

-- This version ensures that the output consists of lists 
-- of equal length. To do so, it trims the input.
chunksOf :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chunksOf n = unfoldr (test . splitAt n) where
  test (_, []) = Nothing
  test x       = Just x
```

Then we can take your `[String]` and turn it into `[[String]]`, a list of lists each corresponding to `String` components of a line. We `map` `concat` over that list to merge up each line from its components, then use `unlines` to glue them all together.

```
grid :: Int -> [String] -> String
grid n = unlines . map concat . chunksOf n
```

Then we can print that string if desired

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ grid 2 list1
```

---

Edit: apparently there is a `chunksOf` in a fairly popular library [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split). Their version is to my knowledge identical to mine, though it's implemented a little differently. Both of ours ought to satisfy

```
chunksOf n xs ++ chunksOf n ys == chunksOf n (xs ++ ys)
```

whenever `` length xs `mod` n == 0 ``.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand `chunksOf`. What exactly do the `test (_, [])` and `test x` lines do?

Comment: `splitAt n` has type `[a] -> ([a], [a])`—it splits a list into two pieces at `n`. If the second piece is empty then `n` is larger than the length of your input list; you've reached the end. `unfoldr` has almost the same type, it takes a function *almost like* `(a -> (b, a))` which generates one `b` from an `a` while creating a new `a` to repeat the process. Unfortunately, this leads to an infinite loop—so we actually use a function `(a -> Maybe (b,a))` where `Nothing` means to stop unfolding. Finally, `test` just stops the `unfoldr` when the second piece from `splitAt` is empty.

Comment: To take a closer look, consider what happens when `test = Just`.

Comment: That makes sense. I ended up going with the Data.List.Split route as all I have to add myself is the grid function. It's working very well. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, `Data.List.Split` is one of those missing-from-Prelude libraries that I always forget about but never feel too bad about including. I'm always surprised it's not a Platform package.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
mapM_ putStrLn [(take 2 list1), (drop 2 list1)]
```

where `take` and `drop` return lists with the expected number of elements. `take 2` takes two elements and `drop 2` drops the first two elements.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `mapM_ putStrLn [(take 2 list1), (drop 2 list1)]

<interactive>:337:25:
    Couldn't match expected type 'Char' with actual type '[Char]'
    Expected type: [Char]
      Actual type: [[Char]]
    In the second argument of 'take', namely 'list1'
    In the expression: (take 2 list1)`

Comment: `list1` is currently a _list of strings_ (even though the strings are only one letter long); the compiler is telling you it wants a _list of chars_. Change all the double-quotes to single-quotes in your definition of `list1` and it should work.

Comment: Alternatively, you could explicitly lower the dimension of the input list by first doing `map head` over `list1` and then applying @SimeonVisser's solution.

Comment: @poorsod That's note really great code. It'll crash if any of the strings are empty, and silently ignore data if any of them are more than one length. In other words, it'll only work under the assumption that *all* the strings are single characters in which case you should use a datatype which represents that, namely `Char`. Or you should handle the strings as strings, and change Simeon's solution to something like `mapM_ putStr (intercalate ["\n"] [take 2 list1, drop 2 list1]) >> putChar '\n'`.

Comment: @Ben - you're right, I should have pointed out the assumptions and limitations in the comment. It'll do the job if the input data is guaranteed to be of the form that OP gave, though.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at **tel** link [Data.List.Split](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split), another solution can be built on using **chop**.
Define as follow into the lib,

```
chop :: ([a] -> (b, [a])) -> [a] -> [b]
chop _ [] = []
chop f as = b : chop f as'
  where (b, as') = f as
```

Then following's simeon advice we end with this one liner,

```
let fun n = mapM_ putStrLn . chop (splitAt n)
```

chop appears to be a nice function, enough to be mentioned here to illustrate an alternative solution. (unfoldr is great too).

Answer (score 0):

Beginner attempt:

```
myOut :: [String] -> IO ()
myOut [] = putStr "\n" 
myOut (x:xs) = 
    do if x=="@"
       then putStrLn x
       else putStr x

       myOut xs



ghci>myOut ["#", "@", "#", "#"]
#@
##
ghci>
```